# Running java file via command line with external library using classpath

Tags: java, command-line, classpath

I'm on Windows and I have a java class file called WebCrawler.class located inside a folder. Also in this folder is a jar file called commons-validator-1.6.jar, and WebCrawler uses functionality from that jar file. WebCrawler is part of a package called cloud.simplecrawl. I navigate to that folder via command line and compile with:

```
javac -cp commons-validator-1.6.jar WebCrawler.java
```

Compilation happens just fine.

Then, I want to run that program, WebCrawler.class, but I can't figure out the exact syntax for the java call, and I feel like I've tried everything. I know it should be some form of:

```
java -cp <something here?> commons-validator-1.6.jar Webcrawler
```

But I can't figure it out! Please help!

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Does `java -cp commons-validator-1.6.jar WebCrawler` not work for you?

Comment: @Slaw No, unfortunately it doesn't! I get the error "Could not find or load main class WebCrawler"

Comment: Is `WebCrawler.class` in the working directory? Does `WebCrawler` have a package?

Comment: Yes, it is in the working directory. WebCrawler.java, WebCrawler.class, and commons-validator-1.6.jar are all in the working directory. This directory is called "simplecrawl". I did declare a package, and my working directory is the tail-end of that package: cloud.simplecrawl, and WebCrawler is in that package.

Comment: The package is cloud.simplecrawl and the directory path that I'm in is \src\cloud\simplecrawl and all of those files are in that directory.

Comment: You may need to set the working directory so that `cloud/simplecrawl/WebCrawler.class` is the relative path to that class file. Then you can try `java -cp path/to/commons-validator-1.6.jar cloud.simplecrawl.WebCrawler`.

Comment: So, essentially, I need to "back out" to the starting directory of the package?

Comment: @Slaw I tried that, so now I'm in a folder that contains commons-validator-1.6.jar. Also inside this folder is a folder called cloud, inside of which is a folder called simplecrawl, and in THAT folder is WebCrawler.java. I compiled everything and it works fine, but running it still says "could not find or load main class cloud.simplecrawl.WebCrawler" when I use the command you suggested.

Comment: @Slaw I figured it out! I had to back out, like you said, but then the command needed to be: java -cp .\;commons-validator-1.6.jar cloud.simplecrawl.WebCrawler

Thank you! You got me there.